# How to solve this system of the 1st order equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

This is a problem from the book:

$$x_1' = x_2\\
x_2' = -x_1\\
x_1(0) = 2\\ 
x_0(0) = 0$$

The problem says transform the system of the 1st order differential equations into
a single differential equation and solve it.

My approach:

I get $x_1'' + x_1 = 0$ by eliminating $x_2$.

How do I use the initial condition?

How to finish the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever solved second degree differential equations?

Comment: Another way of "solving" this is to forget about the initial conditions. Do you know a set of two common functions that behave like that? The derivative of one is the other, and vice-versa (almost)... If you already know the answer, it is thus easier to solve your second degree differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the equation $x_1'' = - x_1$, as you rightly pointed out. You also have $x_1(0) = 2$ and $x_1'(0) = x_2(0) = 0$. This means you have a standard 2nd degree linear differential equation problem:

$$x_1'' + x_1 = 0\\
x_1(0) = 2\\
x_1'(0) = 0$$

which you can solve using standard technicques for LDE-s